# Proof of a simple theorem on measurability

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, proof-explanation

I need to prove the following theorem:

*Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Then
$$
Y = f(X)
$$
for some measurable function $f$ if and only if 
$$
\sigma(Y)\subset\sigma(X).
$$*

The implication $\Rightarrow$ is straightforward. The other implication $\Leftarrow$ requires the construction of $f$. I have found the following proof:

*Suppose that $\sigma(Y)\subset\sigma(X)$. We want to find $f$. For fixed 
$n$ consider the set 
$$
A_{n,m}=\left\{\omega\in\Omega\left| m\,\frac{1}{2^n}\leq Y(\omega)<(m+1)\,\frac{1}{2^n}\right.\right\},\quad m=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,...
$$
Since $A_{n,m}\in\sigma(Y)$ then $A_{n,m}\in\sigma(X)$ and hence 
$$
A_{n,m}=\left\{\omega\in\Omega\left| X(\omega)\in B_{m,n}\right.\right\}
$$
Consider the sequence of functions
$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{m}m\,\frac{1}{2^n}\,I_{\left\{x\in B_{m,n}\right\}}
$$*

The proof then continues claiming that, for all $x$, the sequence $f_{n}(x)$ is monotonically increasing, and then has a limit. I cannot see this, any suggestion?

Comment: What is $B_{m,n}$?

Comment: Some borel subset of the real line, it exists for sure.